# UI issue in XML Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am trying the following in XML

[image]

The left layout is perfect has come up properly but right layout the text is not getting moved down inspite of me putting padding etc. And also I am not able to insert two buttons like the image to my right layout. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/productThumbnailLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/abcd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="450dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/product_details"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
                </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLayouts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/productThumbnailLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/grid_product_text_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/abcd">

                <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/default_numbers"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    pixlui:clearclipboardcontent="true"
                    pixlui:copyandpaste="false"
                    pixlui:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/botholdandnew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_label"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/oldLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="1dp">

                    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/abcd">

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Can you some one help me out on this?

Thanks!

Comment: you should check constraint layout instead of having nested layouts

Comment: Got some help from Rumit but strangely listview is not showing fully.  Check the image: ibb.co/nOZPaH, Few things are cut..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Product Desc"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="sample" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="order" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Will try and get back in few seconds.

Comment: Rumit;: Thanks for the help but I am not able view the full in listview. Why? Any idea? Check the image: https://ibb.co/nOZPaH